# Restrict or prevent drawing functionality?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I've created a Google Sheets spreadsheet that is shared with anonymous users. All users have Edit permission because I want them to contribute data to the spreadsheet.

The problem is that some users are just plain trolls and tries to spam the sheet with useless information. I have tried using data validation, google scripts and other features to restrict them as much access as possible. However, they can still create a drawing and add a textbox or image to it.

As there are no granular Edit permission controls, I'm not sure how I can set this up properly. I could grant them Comment-only access, but some users just have no idea how to use a simple spreadsheet.

So I'm just wondering if it's possible to lock down certain functions in the spreadsheet? Or is there some sort of google script I can use that scans the spreadsheet for drawings and deletes them automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible to achieve in Google Sheets (eg. to lock down certain functions like "inserting of drawings" etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found my own solution. You can remove drawings using Google Script.

Just use the following and trigger on edit:

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31184459/how-do-you-delete-an-image-from-a-google-sheet
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52602177/deleting-images-in-google-sheet-via-script-error

function removeImages() {

  // Deletes all images in sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Enter your sheet name here");
  var images = sheet.getImages();
  images.map(function(img){img.remove();});

}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on it a bit so that those googling for this in the future can understand what you did?